# How do I choose a spatial unit for fixed effects model

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, panel-data, regression-coefficients, fixed-effects-model

I have a panel dataset of 40,000 observations, that is 8,000 parishes and 5 years. When I run a fixed effects regression, using parish as a spatial unit, it shows negative adjusted R2 and rather meaningless coefficients. However when I switch to a much larger unit, county (parishes are grouped into 42 counties) the model works fine. Is this a common problem? How can this finding be explained?

Comment: What is it you are testing ? What is your question and your model formula ?

Comment: My dependent variable is a share of workers on long term contracts. I test the effect of 10 variables, including topographic factors, population density, availability of alternative employment opportunities etc. Population density is in a log form, all others are in the original form.

Answer (score -1):

You are not able at present to detect a parish effect, but you detect a country effect. This might be because the parish effect is not independent form the country.

If you are not directly interested for the effect of parish and country in themselves, which you do not seem to be according to your answer, you might want to instead "correct" for them.

In this case the best approach would be to tun a mixed effect model, which would include the variables you mention in your comment as fixed effect, and `parish` nested in `country` as a random factor : `+(1|country/parish)`.

Comment: Thank you. Does this mean that I have fixed effects at a county level, and below that, random effects at a parish level?

Comment: Welcome to the site. At present this is more of a comment 
than an answer. You could [edit] to expand it, perhaps by giving a 
summary of the information at the link, or we can 
convert it into a comment for you.

Comment: Thank you. I agree that the text above is a comment rather than an answer. In response, I’d like to clarify that I am very much interested in fixed effects. My problem is that I know the theory but have limited practical experience. All my variables are at a parish level, and I expected to find the fixed effects for parishes. However I can only see them at a higher level of a county. The question is whether this is a common occurrence, to be explained by limited deviation of variables by parish, or something odd and suspicious?

Comment: This is definitely not odd and suspicious.

Comment: Great, thanks! If it is not odd, am I correct when I explain this by small variation of my dependent variable by parish, and larger variation at a county level?

Comment: Not really no. The variation caused by parish might differ according to the country the parish is in. But if you want to analyse the effect of parish and country, it is better to have them as fixed effects instead of random factors.